# AWS cognito Login with google is not working in Angular 2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, google-signin, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito Federated External Identity Providers in angular2 (typescript) but not found any help on it. I got AWS Cognito function which can be used in javascript code to get AWS Cognito response for google (social) login and it's giving an error in Angular2.

I got following method from this link [Amazon Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/google.html)

```
     // Google+ login API integration  ----------

    signinCallback(authResult) {

      console.log(authResult);

      // if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
      if (authResult['id_token']) {

         // Add the Google access token to the Cognito credentials login map.

         AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: environment.identityPoolId,
            Logins: {
               'accounts.google.com': authResult['id_token']
            }
         });

         // Obtain AWS credentials
```

> AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
>                   // Access AWS resources here.
>                });

Error: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'CredentialsOptions'

```
      }
    }
```

--

In the above code, I'm getting this error -

*Property 'get' does not exist on type 'CredentialsOptions'*

It would be very much helpful for me if we can get a proper method to be used instead of

AWS.config.credentials.get();

Thanks in advance.